# How do I get this if-statement with jQuery .css to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery code (I know the if statement isn't jQuery), the CSS property "right" for the class "slider" does NOT equal 30, yet "container" is still fading out on mousedown.. What am I doing wrong?

I want it to be: if the class of slider has a "right" CSS property equal to 30 pixels, then fadeout the container.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").mousedown(function() {
        if ($('.slider')
            .css({'right':30})
        ) {
        $('.container')
            .fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".slider").mousedown(function() {
        if ($('.slider').css('right') == 30) {
            $('.container').fadeOut('slow');
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

`$('.slider').css({'right':30})` returns an array object which always evaluates to true.

You want `if ($('.slider').css('right') == "30px")` ...

Comment: Additional (because it might not be obvious to the OP): The code `$('.slider').css({'right':30})` is applying the right css property with a value of 30 which is why it returns an array and evaluates to true.

Comment: yeah hadn't considered that further side=effect .. good catch

Answer (score 5):

Maybe:

```
if($('.slider').css('right') == '30'){ ... }
```

There might be a unit, like `px` at the end of the value there. Not sure.